# Hex editor or fixer for corrupted files

Tags: php, data-recovery

Recently I recover my .php and .txt files but they are corrupted , after some researches I found they corrupted because the `header` is damaged .

I research again and found [Hexed.it](https://hexed.it/) when I upload the .php file to it give me the fixed file [image] ,it's good but not really what I need

So any software recommendation / alternative to it ?

Comment: Why do you need an hex editor ? What do you mean by "header" ? Txt files doesn't have such thing...

Comment: "because the header is damaged" - maybe you mean the encoding of the file was changed? "but not really what I need" - so, what do you need?

Comment: @Amessihel I'm talking about php files .

Comment: @w3d it's "corrupted" in windows when I open the file it's give me symbols , in Ubuntu I get the file maybe damaged or corrupted .

Comment: As Amessihel suggested above, `.php` and `.txt` are both just ordinary "text files"; there is no "header". Unless you are referring to the BOM (Byte Order Mark when saving as UTF-8)? If you are seeing a few strange "symbols" then it may simply have the wrong "encoding" - most text/code editors allow you to change the encoding of a file. Simply opening and saving the document in some editors might correct the encoding. "in Ubuntu I get the file maybe damaged or corrupted" - is that an error that is specifically reported? Can you add a screenshot of a "corrupted" file?

Comment: Most importantly: "recovered"... how? And why is the code shown above not what you need? Please clarify.

Comment: This question has been also posted here: https://superuser.com/questions/1169070/fix-corrupted-files-after-recovery and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41735970/fix-corrupted-files-after-recovery